# "products of high reliability" VS "products with high reliability"

Tags: prepositions

> Company A delivers products ***of*** high reliability.

Is this sentence  clear enough to convey the meaning company A provides highly reliable productis.

Or I should say:

> Company A delivers products ***with*** high reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

> Company A delivers products of high reliability.

the emphasis is on the **product**. So the products will be of **high reliability**. Although, *quality* is a much better choice of word in such a scenario.

On the other hand, when you say

> Company A delivers products with high reliability.

the emphasis falls on the act of *delivering* those products. In this case, the delivery is done with **high reliability**, with no inference to the quality of the products themselves.